Use a mesh object to controll the shape of a texture on another object
Is there a way to controll the shape of a texture on one object and using a different object as the controller?
I know there's mapping nodes that control the rotation, location, and scale of a texture but I also want to give it a custom shape as well.
Like you can use a cube to change the location of a blue dot texture on a sphere but you can't use that cube to turn the dot into a star.
I guess I'm trying to project the shape of one object into a texture of another object. Is there a way to do that?


Hello and welcome. In your title you mentioned "shape of texture" but it seems you just want to swap the texture from one texture with a dot to another texture with a star? or do you literally want to change the shape of the texture? So are there 2 textures or 1 texture involved? Can you manually model the before and after and provide a screenshot of an example before and after look?

Please avoid text written inside images, always prefer typing it directly in the body of the post instead. Image content can't be indexed and thus can't be readily found when searching in the future. Updates are difficult because it can't be easily edited in case of mistakes, nor updated in case of future changes. It doesn't follow the fonts and style of the website automatically, and doesn't work with screen readers. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed instead [edit] them into your post.

Thank you for providing more info, but it would be better to also provide an image of the 'before' state and another image of the 'after' or expected state so we can better understand the problem.
